# express static: serve pages with dynamic content

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.static to serve some pages, lets say you browse to:

```
https://amazing.com/static
```

it's serving the content of a directory, which in my case is an index.html and a JS script, great!

Now, I would like to achieve the following:

If you browse to

```
https://amazing.com/static/whatever
```

I want to serve the same page as above, but keep the 'whatever' URL intact, where 'whatever' is some identifier for some dynamic content.

The client should be on that URL, so that the client-side JS script can fetch content based on the path, after loading & displaying the static page.

Not sure this can be achieved with express.static - I'm new to the node / express ecosystem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this, but not using `express.static()`. You need to define a dynamic route that ignores the identifier in the path and responds with the desired static file:

```
// ...
const { resolve } = require('path');
// wherever your static files are, relative to this file
const myStaticDirectory = './www';

app.use('/static', express.static(resolve(__dirname, myStaticDirectory)));

app.get('/static/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, myStaticDirectory, 'index.html'));
});
```